# Factors of -2 that sum to

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to simplify this equation: $x^2+x-2$. I put it on WolframAlpha and it gives me this:

> The factors of -2 that sum to are $2$ and $-1$. So, $x^2+x-2 = (x+2)(x-1)$

Can someone please explain to me what does this mean? How is this technique called?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that there is a word missing. Presumably, it should say, "The factors of $-2$ that sum to $1$ are $2$ and $-1$."

Comment: It should be mentioned that while this "*method*" works for factoring quadratics whose roots are integers, it will fail to find the factorization when they are not.  For example $x^2+x+1$.  The factors of $1$ are $1$ and $-1$, but you cannot add these in any way to get the coefficient of the middle term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to *factor* (not simplify) the *expression* (not equation) $x^2 + x - 2$.

The coefficient on the $x$ term is $\color{red}{1}$.  The constant coefficient is $\color{blue}{-2}$.

Therefore, $x^2 + x - 2$ factors into $(x-a)(x-b)$, where $a+b = \color{red}{1}$ and $ab = \color{blue}{-2}$.  The values of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy both of these constraints are $a = -2$ and $b = 1$.  Therefore we have:
$$ x^2 + x - 2 = (x + 2)(x - 1)$$

As mentioned before, this is factoring.  This specific technique (of finding the $a$ and $b$) doesn't have a name, as far as I know.

Comment: For a name, perhaps you could call it a special case of using [vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to factor

> $$x^{ 2 }+x-2=x^{ 2 }+x+\frac { 1 }{ 4 } -\frac { 1 }{ 4 } -2={ \left( x+\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-\frac { 9 }{ 4 } =\left( x+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } -\frac { 3 }{ 2 }  \right) \left( x+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 3 }{ 2 }  \right) \\ =\left( x-1 \right) \left( x+2 \right) $$